# Using Vue.js I am getting strange behavior in the two methods tied to click events on two buttons, Save and Delete

Tags: vue.js

First the two buttons in the EditInstruction Modal.

```
<!-- SUBMIT/ delete BUTTONS -->
                <div class="flex items-center gap-8">           
                    <button class="btn-warning mt-4" @click="this.deleteInstruction(editInstruction)">Delete Instruction</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary mt-4" @click='saveEditInstruction'>Save Instruction</button>
                </div>
```

Next the method to handle the Delete button click...

```
deleteInstruction(_instruction){
            console.log('deleteInstruction _instruction.id = %s', _instruction.id)
            this.swalCustom(`Delete ${_instruction.requestpath}?`, `Are you sure you want to delete ${_instruction.requestpath}?`, 'warning', true, true, 'I am sure.', 'Cancel')
            .then(results=>{
                if(results.isConfirmed){
                    this.swalLoading('Deleting...')
                    _url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/instructions/' + _instruction.id + '/'
                    console.log( '_url = %s ', _url)
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        getAPI.delete(_url)
                        .then(res=>{
                            this.swalSuccess('Deleted')
                            
                        })
                        .catch(err=>{
                            this.swalError('Error in deleting ')
                            
                        })
                        this.loadInstructions()
                        this.toggleModal('editInstructionModal')
                    }, 1000)
                }
            })
        },
```

Next is the method to handle the submit button click.

```
saveEditInstruction(row){
              console.log('saveEditInstruction()')
              this.swalLoading('Updating Instruction...')
              //check for completeness
              if(true){
                  console.log('saveEditInstruction row.id = %s', row.id)
                  setTimeout(()=>{
                  // POST API FOR ADDING Instruction
                  
                  getAPI.put('http://localhost:8000/api/instructions/' + row.id + '/', row)
                  .then(res=>{
  
                      // SETS MESSAGE FOR RESPONSE
                      let message = `Instruction ${row.requestpath} ${row.description} has been successfully added.`
  
                      // DISPLAYS SUCCESS SCREEN/MODAL
                      this.swalSuccess(message)
                      this.loadInstructions()
                      this.toggleModal('editInstructionModal')
                  })
                  .catch(err=>{
                      this.swalError(err)
                  })
              }, 1000)
              this.loadInstructions()
              this.toggleModal('editInstructionModal')
              }
  
        },
```

and the console.log showing the delete function call and then unexplained jump to the save method.

```
deleteInstruction _instruction.id = 1
InstructionsTableModal.vue:438 saveEditInstruction()
InstructionsTableModal.vue:442 saveEditInstruction row.id = 1
InstructionsTableModal.vue:330 loadInstructions()
mixins.js:130
```

I have tried renaming things.  I have tried moving methods up and down the chain.  I tried disabling the Save button. I deleted the browser cache.

I tried disabling the `this.swalCustom(`Delete ${_instruction.requestpath}?`,` Are you sure you want to delete ${_instruction.requestpath}?`, 'warning', true, true, 'I am sure.', 'Cancel')` to no avail, console.log does not change.

Additional info.  I renamed the save method to `saveEditInstruction` and ran it again, and the Console.log follows.

````
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <BaseTransition appear=true persisted=false mode=undefined  ... > 
  at <Transition appear="" name="slide-fade" > 
  at <BaseTransition appear=false persisted=false mode=undefined  ... > 
  at <Transition onClose=fn > 
  at <Modal width="w-[38rem]" ref="editInstructionModal" onClose=fn > 
  at <InstructionsTableModal core=true width="w-[48rem]" ref="InstructionsTableModal"  ... > 
  at <TableMx onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {validate: ƒ, formatPrice: ƒ, formatPriceIntl: ƒ, formatDateTime: ƒ, …} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
warn2 @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38
logError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:212
handleError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:204
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:339
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:218 Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.saveEditInstruction is not a function
    at InstructionsTableModal.vue:160:36
    at runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1450:16
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:339:9)
(anonymous) @ InstructionsTableModal.vue:160
(anonymous) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1450
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:339
tablemx:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received```

If that helps.
````

Comment: Avoid using `this` inside templates - it is needless. The `saveEditInstruction` expects an argument - but in your template there is no argument so the function will receive the native Click event as its argument. Keep in mind that buttons of type `submit` will also trigger a submission of their parent FORM - unless their handler of Click event calls `preventDefault()`. And if the FORM does not have an explicit `action` parameter - the browser will simply reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was in the two lines with the buttons.

```
<div class="flex items-center gap-8">           
                    <button class="btn-warning mt-4" @click="this.deleteInstruction(editInstruction)">Delete Instruction</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary mt-4" @click='saveEditInstruction'>Save Instruction</button>
                </div>
```

Changed to

```
<div class="flex items-center gap-8">           
                    <button type="button" class="btn-warning mt-4" @click="this.deleteInstruction(editInstruction)">Delete Instruction</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary mt-4" @click='saveEditInstruction'>Save Instruction</button>
                </div>
```

**Apparently** not having the type="button" let it cascade to the save submit method.